# If $H\triangleleft G$ then $Z(H)\leq Z(G)$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $H\triangleleft G$ then $Z(H)\leq Z(G)$. Is this true?I need so help for starters.

Answer (score 4):

Counter example:

Let $A_3$ be the alternating subgroup of $S_3$. Since the index: $[S_3:A_3]=2$, then $A_3$ is normal in $S_3$, but $Z(A_3)=A_3$ and $Z(S_3)=\{1\}$.

Comment: what is true always is that for any pair of subsets $A\subset B$ in a groups $G$ we have $Z(A)\supset Z(B)$.

Comment: $Z(A) \supseteq Z(B) \cap A$